# SQL Server 2008 give default instance name

Tags: sql-server-2008, instance

when I installed, I didn't give the instance a name, and I should have.  Is there any way I can go back and add the name to the default instance?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - you Can't.  You need to get the SQL Server install disk, and Add a new instance - a named instance - that you want.